# 'Top Questions' and 'Top Answers' headings interchanged on stackexchange user page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, top-questions, top-answers

On my SE user page, my most popular questions are displayed under the heading `Top Answers` and my most popular answers are displayed under the heading `Top Questions`. (i.e The two seem to have been interchanged)

Comment: I am seeing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, this was introduced after refactoring yesterday. It's fixed now.